# Dijkstra's Algorithm in String-type Graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, stl, dijkstra

I am making an inter-city route planning program where the graph that is formed has string-type nodes (e.g. LHR, ISB, DXB). It's undirected but weighted, and is initialized as:

```
map<pair<string, string>, int> city;
```

and then I can add edges by for example:

```
Graph g;
g.addEdge("DXB", "LHR", 305);
g.addEdge("HTR", "LHR", 267);
g.addEdge("HTR", "ISB", 543);
```

and the resultant output will be:

```
        ISB     LHR
DXB     0       305
HTR     543     267
```

Now, the question... I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm in this graph but so far have been unable to correctly run it on string-type nodes and opposed to learning and doing it on int-type nodes. Can someone guide me through the correct steps of implementing it in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: you can map every node to an integer with help of map<string, int>, assign every node to a different integer value, then make a graph with whose int values and run Dijkstra. For query get int value for nodes from the map and use those int values for querying

Comment: Note that a map with key type pair makes it inefficient to find all neighbors of a node; A more efficient way would be to use something like `template<typename IdType> struct Connection; template<typename IdType>struct Vertex { IdType m_id; std::vector<Connection<IdType>> m_neighbors; }; template<typename IdType> struct Connection { int m_weight; Vertex<IdType>* m_target; };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure used by a graph application has a big impact on the efficiency and ease of coding.

Many designs start off with the nodes.  I guess the nodes, in the problems that are being modelled, often have a physical reality while the links can be abstract relationships.  So it is more natural to start writing a node class, and add on the links later.

However, when coding algorithms that solve problems in graph theory, it becomes clear that the links are the real focus.  So, lets start with a link class.

```
class cLink
{
public:
    cLink(int c = 1)
        : myCost(c)
    {
    }
    int myCost;         // a constraint e.g. distance of a road, max xapacity of a pipe
    int myValue;        // a calculated value, e.g. actual flow through a pipe
};
```

If we store the out edges of node in a map keyed by the destination node index, then the map will be an attribute of the source node.

```
class cNode
{
public:
    cNode(const std::string &name = "???")
        : myName(name)
    {
    }
    std::string myName;
    std::map<int, cLink> myLink;    // out edges of node, keyed by destination
};
```

We have links and nodes, so we are ready to construct a class to store the graph

```
class cGraph {
public:
std::map<int, cNode> myG; // the graph, keyed by internal node index
};
```

Where did the node index come from?  Humans are terrible at counting, so better the computer generates the index when the node is added.

```
cGraph::createNode( const std::string& name )
{
    int n = myG.size();
    myG.insert(std::make_pair(n, cNode(name)));
}
```

Don't implement this! It has a snag - it can create two nodes with the same name.  We need to be able to check if node with a specified name exists.

```
int cGraph::find(const std::string &name)
{
    for (auto n : myG)
    {
        if (n.second.myName == name)
        {
            return n.first;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This is inefficient.  However, it only needs to be done once when the node is added.  Then the algorithms that search through the graph can use fast lookup of nodes by index number.

Now we can prevent two nodes being created with the same name

```
    int cGraph::findoradd(const std::string &name)
    {
        // search among the existing nodes
        int n = find(name);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            // node does not exist, create a new one
            // with a new index and add it to the graph
            n = myG.size();
            myG.insert(std::make_pair(n, cNode(name)));
        }
        return n;
    }
```

Humans, in addition to being terrible counters, are also over confident in their counting prowess.  When they specify a graph like this

```
1 -> 2
1 -> 3
```

Let’s not be taken in.  Let’s regard these numbers as names and continue to use our own node index system.

```
/** Add costed link between two nodes
 *
 * If the nodes do not exist, they will be added.
 *
 */

            void addLink(
                const std::string & srcname,
                const std::string & dstname,
                double cost = 1)
            {
                int u = findoradd(srcname);
                int v = findoradd(dstname);
                myG.find(u)->second.myLink.insert(
                           std::make_pair(v, cLink(cost)));
                if (!myfDirected)
                    myG.find(v)->second.myLink.insert(
                           std::make_pair(u, cLink(cost)));
            }
```

With the addition of a few getters and setters, we are ready to start implementing graph algorithms!

To see an complete implementation, including Dijsktra, using these ideas, check out [PathFinder](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2).

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to explain this to me. This was a fantastic read and cleared me up on my points on Dijkstra's algorithm. However, for the past few hours, I have still been unable to successfully implement the algorithm in my code. Can I send you (or begin a new question with) the complete graph class code so that you could help me further? If you have the time that is, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment, this answer helped me understand enough to successfully implement the algorithm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The core problem is that when we work on graphs with integer vertices, the index of the adjacency list represents the node (since the indexes are also numbers). Now instead of using adjacency list like `vector<pair<int, int> > adj[N]`we can use `map<string,vector<string, int> > adj`. Now `adj["DXB"]` will contain a vector of pairs of the form `<string, int>` which is the `<name, weight>` for the cities connected to `"DXB"`.

If this approach seems very complex, then you use some extra memory to map a city to a number, and then you can code everything considering that the graph has integer vertices.